# How do I connect to an existing Github repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github

I've a repository in Github with a couple of commits. Now, I'd like to download the entire project to an other laptop. I've created just a solution in Visual Studio with the same name.

How do I download the entire project?

Answer (score 1):

You could use git clone command.

usage: git clone repos url

ex.
   git clone git@github.com:solos/Spoon-Knife.git
   or git clone https://github.com/solos/Spoon-Knife.git

Comment: only command prompt? No way to use click here and there in visual studio?

Comment: You could try this. [getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx)